# BUG - after SUPEE-8788 i can't remove Samples row of downloadable products

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, patch

i'm using magento 1.9.2.4 patched with SUPEE-8788.

Everything seems to be ok a part an issue, ...i'm not able anymore to remove rows in samples

of downloadable products.

I mean when i click the "X" to remove the row of samples, like you can see in the image, nothing happen and i'm not able to save the product [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Er0.png)

I saw the same problem happens also in a fresh clean copy of magento 1.9.3.1

Does anyone know why this happens?...can you help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, this is a bug in SUPEE-8788

Open samples.phtml inside `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable`

Find the function

> ```
> remove : function(event){
>     var element = $(Event.findElement(event, 'tr'));
>     alertAlreadyDisplayed = false;
>     if(element){
>         element.down('input[type="hidden"].__delete__').value = '1';
>         element.down('div.flex').remove();
>         element.addClassName('no-display');
>         element.addClassName('ignore-validate');
>         element.hide();
>     }
> },
> ```

and replace it with

> ```
> remove : function(event){
>     var element = $(Event.findElement(event, 'tr'));
>     alertAlreadyDisplayed = false;
>     if(element){
>         element.down('input[type="hidden"].__delete__').value = '1';
>         Element.select(element, 'div.flex').each(function(elm){
>             elm.remove();
>         });
>         element.addClassName('no-display');
>         element.addClassName('ignore-validate');
>         element.hide();
>     }
> },
> ```

I hope you will solve the problem